# Fixed position modal scrolling/focus

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I recently built a JS/CSS modal system. The project was using Bootstrap modals, but was pushing it to the limits by putting forms and large amounts of content inside of them that weren't scrolling or focus correctly on mobiles.

The modal system can be triggered [here](http://getdeveloperjobs.com) by clicking most of the footer links (Privacy Policy, Terms and Conditions, etc.).

**General problem:** the modal has fixed position CSS that causes the body to scroll down when you scroll on the modal. I did my best to try and make that not matter, mostly through "overflow", "height" and some light "z-index" stuff. It worked really well on iOS, but not on Android we found out.

**Specifics:** the X button isn't clickable when the body's scroll position isn't at the top, and the modal won't scroll up until the body's scroll position is at the top.

I understand that I am forcing it... conversion is important for the site, and it is truly important to not reload the page and keep them in "the funnel." Should I change the way this is set up so that instead of trying to display a scrollable element *on top* of the body, it *replaces* the body temporarily? Or is there a CSS fix for this that i'm missing? I'm pretty stuck.

Comment: Android Browser on 4.2.2. I pulled Google Analytics data and we had 13k Chrome users and 10k Android Browser users for the month, so I can't really just ignore it... if possible. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I ended up using! HTML...

```
<body>

  <main id="main">
    Site Content
  </main>

  <aside id="modals">
    Modals In Here
  </aside>

</body>
```

For the CSS, I did a media query that only targeted mobiles. The CSS displayed all of the modals in a standard way (not with `position:fixed`), using `position:static` and `display:block`. The content, though it is a "modal", is being displayed in a 100% standard, supported way. There are now no bugs associated with scrolling/focus.

The JS is adding a class to the body that I am using in the CSS selectors. As for the rest of the JS, I am going to post the libraries to GitHub and make them reusable. +1 if you're interested!

This system is still live [here](http://getdeveloperjobs.com).